# display pager depending upon the number of records

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

I am using kendo grid.I have defined like,

```
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
            dataSource:datasource, 
           pageable: true,
            columns: [
                    { field: "ProductId", title: "ProductId" },
                    { field: "ProductType", title: "ProductType" },
                    { field: "Name", title: "Name" },
                    { field: "Created", title: "Created" }
                ],
          });
    });
```

I am able to display pager in my grid.but what I want is If the records in the grid is more than 20,Then only I want to display pager ,else don't want to display pager ,can u tell me how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically this is not supported. You can try to work-around it with some JavaScript. For example the following script after initializing the Grid should achieve similar behavior:

```
$(function(){
     if($('#gridName').data().kendoGrid.dataSource.total()>20){
          $('#gridName .k-grid-pager').hide();
     }
})
```